# Separar los componentes de una fecha en diferentes variables

Tags: c#

```
using System;
public class Videoclub{
    struct fecha{
        public string dia;
        public string mes;
        public string anyo;
    }
    struct pelicula{
        public string titulo;
        public string director;
        public string estreno;
        public fecha prestamo;
        public fecha devolucion;
    }
    public static void Main(){
        pelicula[] numPelicula = new pelicula[1000];
        string opcion;
        DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
        int ultPosVacia = 0;
        string prestamo = "";
        string devolucion = "";
        string mess = "";
        bool salir = false;

        do{

            Console.WriteLine(thisDay.ToString("D"));
            Console.WriteLine("Que quieres hacer");
            Console.WriteLine("Opcion 1 - Insertar nueva pelicula al final");
            Console.WriteLine("Opcion 2 - Borrar pelicula");
            Console.WriteLine("Opcion 3 - Cerrar el programa");

            opcion = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (opcion){
                case "1":
                    Console.Write("Titulo de la pelicula? ");
                        numPelicula[ultPosVacia].titulo = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("Director de la pelicula? ");
                        numPelicula[ultPosVacia].director = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("Año de estreno de la pelicula? ");
                        numPelicula[ultPosVacia].estreno = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("Fecha de prestamo de la pelicula (dd/mm/aaaa)? ");
                        prestamo = Console.ReadLine();
                        numPelicula[ultPosVacia].prestamo.dia = prestamo.Remove(3,8);
                        mess = prestamo.Remove(0,3);
                        numPelicula[ultPosVacia].prestamo.mes = prestamo.Remove(3,5);
                        numPelicula[ultPosVacia].prestamo.anyo = prestamo.Remove(0,6);
                    Console.Write("Fecha de devolucion de la pelicula (dd/mm/aaaa)? ");
                        devolucion = Console.ReadLine();
                        numPelicula[ultPosVacia].devolucion.dia = devolucion.Remove(3,8);
                        mess = devolucion.Remove(0,3);
                        numPelicula[ultPosVacia].devolucion.mes = devolucion.Remove(3,5);
                        numPelicula[ultPosVacia].devolucion.anyo = devolucion.Remove(0,6);

                    ultPosVacia++;
                    Console.ReadKey();

                    break;
                case "2":
                    break;
                case "3":
                    salir = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("*******************************************");
                    break;
            }


        }while(salir==false);

        Console.Clear();
    }
}
```

Error del CMD:

> Excepción no controlada: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: El índice y el recuento deben hacer referencia a una ubicación en la cadena. Nombre del parámetro: count en System.String.Remove(Int32 startIndex, Int32 count) en Videoclub.Main()

Comment: Brother, coloca el código completo indicando por qué falla. Somos desarrolladores y nos ayudamos entre todos, cuando tenemos la información adecuada, la solución está en camino y todos juntos aprendemos :D 
Saludos

Comment: el usuario debe introducir por ejemplo 22/04/2015.
numPelicula[ultPosVacia].devolucion.dia deberia valer 22.
numPelicula[ultPosVacia].devolucion.mes deberia valer 04.
numPelicula[ultPosVacia].devolucion.anyo deberia valer 2015.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar como decidistes escoger los parámetros de esta expresión: `prestamo.Remove(3,8)`? ¿Por qué `3` y `8`? ¿Cómo piensas que eso funciona? Nota aparte, el uso de `Remove` es raro, y hay algunos lugares donde estás usando `prestamo` cuando tu intención es usar `devolucion`.

Comment: en caso de que introduzca 22/04/2015:
elimina desde la posicion 3 (la primera barra), 8 caracteres.

Comment: Las posiciones comienzan con `0`, no `1`. Por lo que la posición `3` es el `0`, no la barra. Con esto en mente, ¿puedes ver por qué no le va a gustar de que le pidas quitar 8 caracteres?

Comment: 1000 gracias ahora lo pruebo, quien me lo explico digamos que se dedica a la docencia pero podria prepararse la clase antes de darla y me he confundido

Comment: Todo esto está documentado y accesible a todos. Es bueno verificar la documentación en casos como estos y hacer pruebas concretas para verificar que las cosas funcionan como uno piensa. Documentación: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error debe provenir de la sentencia siguiente:

```
numPelicula[ultPosVacia].prestamo.dia = prestamo.Remove(3,8);
```

Cuando te pregunté lo que pensabas que esta sentencia hacía, me contestastes:

> en caso de que introduzca 22/04/2015: elimina desde la posicion 3 (la primera barra), 8 caracteres.

Pero eso no es el caso. Las posiciones (o índices) comienzan con `0`, no `1`. Por eso, cuando indicas el índice `3`, en realidad esto se refiere al cuarto caracter, no el tercero.  Y por supuesto, siendo que no existen 8 caracteres a partir del cuarto, esto te da error.

Por eso, en este caso, la expresión correcta era:

```
prestamo.Remove(2,8);
```

o, aun mas sencillo:

```
prestamo.Remove(2);
```

... donde omites el segundo parámetro, lo que significa que va a borrar todos los caracteres a partir del índice especificado.

Te aviso de antemano de que, al corregir este error, te vas a dar cuenta que tienes otros errores más. Si tomas el tiempo de depurar el código, de seguro encontrarás como resolver los demás errores.

---

En lo personal, para este tipo de operaciones, me parece mas sencillo usar `String.Substring` que `String.Remove`, si le quieres echar un vistazo.

O, aun mejor, cuando se trata de fechas, en vez de tratar de extraer los elementos de la fecha a mano, es mejor usar las clases existentes que ya tienen esta lógica integrada.  Por ejemplo, esta es otra forma mas sencilla de extraer la información que buscas usando `DateTime.ParseExact()`:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

// ...

string prestamo = @"22/04/2015";
DateTime fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(prestamo, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int dia = fecha.Day;
int mes = fecha.Month;
int year = fecha.Year;
```

Comment: Talvés sería mejor usar `TryParseExact`, sabiendo que es una entrada del usuario es suceptible a alguna falla, a menos que se enmascare el campo para que se reciba siempre una fecha válida con el formato `dd/MM/yyyy`, o en su caso, sugerirle a @jesusAG28 que en lugar de un `TextBox` use un `DateTimePicker` ;)

Comment: @Flxtr: muy buenas sugerencias. Espero que OP las tome en cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Si solo recibieras la fecha con barras separadoras, lo que puedes hacer es un `split`.

Por ejemplo, si la fecha viene así:

```
var VariableDondeRecibesLaFecha = "06/11/2017";

string[] separarFecha= VariableDondeRecibesLaFecha.Split('/');
string dia = separarFecha[0];
string mes = separarFecha[1];
string anio= separarFecha[2];
```

El resultado sería:

> `dia = "06";`
>
> `mes = "11";`
>
> `anio = "2017";`

Sería otra opción a considerar.